# 100% CPU usage while stressing with SIEGE -c5

Tags: webserver, users, cpu, load

I've tried apache benchmark and siege for stressing my web server, unfortunately my VPS CPU goes 100% with only 5 concurrent users. 
I'm also using cache engine for my wordpress site.

According to the bellow info and results, shoudnt my system be capable to handle much more users?

My system:

```
Linux snf-654323 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Debian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l
MemTotal:        6132080 kB

cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 6
model           : 6
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.0.0
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x1000065
cpu MHz         : 2100.000
cache size      : 512 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 4
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat                              pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm nopl pni cx16 x2apic popcnt hyperv                             isor lahf_lm svm abm sse4a vmmcall
bogomips        : 4200.00
TLB size        : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 6
model           : 6
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.0.0
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x1000065
cpu MHz         : 2100.000
cache size      : 512 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 4
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat                              pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm nopl pni cx16 x2apic popcnt hyperv                             isor lahf_lm svm abm sse4a vmmcall
bogomips        : 4200.00
TLB size        : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Mysqltuner results:

```
-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.43-0+deb7u1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 28B (Tables: 10)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 2M (Tables: 35)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 35

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 3h 0m 41s (122K q [11.259 qps], 7K conn, TX: 626M, RX: 13M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 86% / 14%
[--] Total buffers: 192.0M global + 2.7M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 597.8M (9% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/122K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 20% (31/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/125.0K
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 73.5% (65K cached / 89K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 106 sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 25% (120 on disk / 464 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (89 created / 7K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 78% (96 open / 123 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 6% (68/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (9K immediate / 9K locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 2.1M/128.0M
```

SIEGE results:

```
root@snf-654323:~# siege -c5 -t5M -b http://example.com
** SIEGE 2.70
** Preparing 5 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
Lifting the server siege...      done.                                         T                             ransactions:                    3456 hits
Availability:                 100.00 %
Elapsed time:                 299.74 secs
Data transferred:               2.39 MB
Response time:                  0.43 secs
Transaction rate:              11.53 trans/sec
Throughput:                     0.01 MB/sec
Concurrency:                    4.99
Successful transactions:        3456
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            1.95
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

Comment: You get an up-vote for all the research and detail!

Comment: Anytime!! I used to manage about 1000 servers for a global telcom company with more traffic than Microsoft and just less than Google. We are here to help. There are some real experts here. Some of us are such geeks, we do this for fun!!

Comment: wow!! I can't even imagine what skills and knowledges required for managing such amount of servers! I'm barely running 1 web server haha! I'm a proud geek also and currently studying computer engineering. My university gave us free VM's to play with, so i took the oppurtunity. I hope someday to become a good professional programmer as this field interests me more! :)

Comment: You will be exactly what you seek. Trust me! Just take it one step at a time and learn from the best you can find. I started out as a programmer and quickly became a coder of protocol stacks, drivers, OS(s), back during the age of ARPANet (pre-Internet- did some coding there too) which got me on the inside track for Internet Services consulting as well as systems internals consulting for/to DEC and by relation, Microsoft platforms. Hence all the servers!! Get to the root of how things work and you will smoke the whole IT game.

Comment: ARPANet? You must be very old sir, haha just joking! I wish i could live these days, i guess these things back then were way more exciting than now. May i humbly ask you for an advice about job interviews? I'm gonna work for 6 months in a really colossal company with the chance to keep me after that (if they are pleased). I'm really afraid of my first interview even though my professors recommendations. I'm thinking all the time it may end to a disaster, i always thinking that i don't have enough knowledges, and afraid ofmy dreams will collapse! I really need an advice from someone like you :)

Comment: Back in the days of ARPA-Net, we had no real clue what we were looking at. ;-) It was turned over to the academic community with the thought that some commerce would occur. Back then we had no clue. As for interviews- cover your strengths. Not every job is for every person or the other way around. Just remember that it is a business conversation to see if a trade for services is a good choice for both parties. No job makes or breaks anyone. Sure there are golden opportunities- so it seems, but do try too hard to make things work if they should not. It should be a win win for everyone.

Comment: BTW- I have botched interviews. Everyone has. But in the end, looking back, it did not make a difference if I did not get a particular job. There are plenty of opportunities- some seemed golden, but have turned out not to be. Whew! Dodged a bullet there!! In the end, your life will be exactly what it should be. Job opportunities come and go. The secret is to relax and let the good opportunities happen. Sometimes, it is the odd little ones that turn out to be the best!! You will not die a horrible death if you are nervous. They expect you to be. Just be the best you you can be.

Comment: Thanks for you good words, i'll try my best and hope for a good future. :) Good night sir, it was a pleasure to discuss with you.

Comment: Anytime my friend! We are here for you whenever you need us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the number of users but the number of transactions. You had 3456 in about 300 seconds which equals 11.52 transactions per second with the longest transaction taking 1.95 seconds. This seems within the *good* range to me. You may be able to tune Apache and MySQL some to handle more transactions, but I would not bother until you start to get to 8-10 transactions per second as a more normal basis during busy times.